# namespace shell extension crashes explorer

Tags: windows, shell, namespaces

I have developed a namespace shell extension program in c++, where SHITEMID is defined as follows

```
typedef struct tagENT_PIDL_FILEITEM
{
// SHITEMID
USHORT cb;
// Type identifiers
BYTE magic;
BYTE reserved;
//
WCHAR cDocID[64];
WCHAR cShareID[64];
WCHAR cResourceId[64];
//WCHAR cFileType[10];
WCHAR cFileType[10];
// File data
WIN32_FIND_DATA wfd;
#if defined(_M_X64) || defined(_M_IA64)
// Alignment on 64bit platform
SHORT padding[56];
#endif // _M_X64
} ENT_PIDL_FILEITEM;
```

It works fine on 32-bit Windows 7, but on 64-bit Windows 10, just select the file or folder and press the delete shortcut (delete) or the f2 shortcut (rename).
. Explorer will automatically exit. Do not you know why.

About SHITEMID
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/nse-implement#creating-an-shitemid-structure

Comment: Pidl format should be the same regardless of CPU. Finding this crash without code is impossible. The best solution is for you to debug it yourself...

Comment: I debugged it. It seems that strlen made an error, but I don't know where the error is!